# Resource can not be found in Asp.NET although path is correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am passing values to the action method using the ajax call. My action method name is **TagTargets** and this method has three parameters. I am also giving the exact path also but getting the error **The resource cannot be found.**

```
//Ajax Call to get targets Data
    function TargetsData() {
        var realTags = $('#Raw_Tag_List').val();
        var calculatedTags = $('#Calculated_Tag_List').val();
        var manulTags = $('#Manual_Tag_List').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'TagTargets',
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'RealTags': realTags, 'CalculatedTags': calculatedTags, 'ManulTags':manulTags},
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert('Ok')
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Not ok');
                    }
                }

        });
        debugger;
        }

//Action Method
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult TagTargets(List<string> RealTags, List<string> CalculatedTags, List<string> ManulTags) 
        {

            return Json(true);
        }
```

Comment: u cannot send multiple complex object parameters in the controller method. Make a wrapper class for holding the three objects and keep that as the sole parameter

Answer (score 0):

change your url to a valid url.

```
url: "@Url.Action("TagTargets","ControllerName");",
```